# CSS float not pushing the adjacent element

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I'm trying to make timeline-like objects using react, and vanila css. What I designed looks below:

[image]

Boxes each line composes one component, so two boxes across and a circle marker in between are one group. I simply used `flex` to put them in line, and used `border-left` on right-side textbox's wrapper `div` to make a vertical line.

The problem is with that circle marker. What I originally thought was that if I use `::before` pseudo selector to the right textbox, then that marker will be hung up right beside the right textbox. The code I tried is below:

```js
const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
`

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  width: 50vw;
`

const WrapperWithLine = styled.div`
  width: 50vw;
  border-left: 7px solid grey;
`

const Textbox = styled.div`

`

const TextboxWithMarker = styled.div`
  margin: 0 0 0 1vw;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-size: cover;

    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;

    position: relative;
    left: 1vw;
    float: left;
  }
`

const Component = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Wrapper>
        <Textbox>
          Lorem Ipsum...
        <Textbox>
      </Wrapper>
      <WrapperWithLine>
        <TextboxWithMarker>
          Lorem Ipsum...
        <TextboxWithMarker>
      </WrapperWithLine>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

What I get is that the marker object pushes the adjacent element. So I tried with `float: right;` and `right: 50vw;` so that it will literally "float" on other elements, and it looks okay, but it won't be placed consistently on the right middle of the line.

Is there any better way to make this kind of design? I think this kind of layout is frequently used in the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without setting it all up in React, I crudely recreated this setup using HTML & CSS.

I shuffled around the structure as I would do it this way. I created a div that would house the line, so that it was it's own element, which to me makes things a lot easier to work with. `::before` and `::after` are okay to work with when it is dependent mainly on the element it is joined to. But to me, the line is affected by both the left and right text boxes, so it deserves it's own container. Also in this way, the circle is tied to the line using `::before`, which makes more sense.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50vw;  
}

.textbox {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.line {
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.line:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: green;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="textbox">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="textbox">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="textbox">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="textbox">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="textbox">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="textbox">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this will be a nice reference for me to study CSS! Thank you for the example you made.